# Is it justified to derive a formula of a mapping $T$ by assuming $T$ to be linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-explanation, linear-transformations

I was reading Linear Algebra by Stephen H Friedberg, Insel and Spence. I was reading the Chapter-2 on Linear Transformations, Section-2.5 which is titled as "The Change in Coordinate Matrix".

However, while reading I got stuck with the portion in the section which I present below:

---

We now derive the less obvious rule for the reflection $T$ about the line $y = 2x$. We wish to find an expression for $T(a, b)$ for any $(a, b)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Since $T$ is linear, it is completely determined by its values on a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$. Clearly, $T(1, 2) = (1, 2)$ and $T(-2, 1) = -(-2, 1) = (2, -1)$. Therefore, if we let
$\beta' = \{\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\}$
then $\beta'$ is an ordered basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $[T]_{\beta} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Let $\beta$ be the standard ordered basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$, and let $Q$ be the matrix that changes $\beta'$-coordinates into $\beta$-coordinates. Then $
Q = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$
and $Q^{-1}[T]_{\beta}Q = [T]_{\beta'}$. We can solve this equation for $[T]_{\beta}$ to obtain that $[T]_{\beta} = Q[T]_{\beta'}Q^{-1}$.

Because $Q^{-1} = \frac{1}{5}\begin{pmatrix} 1&& 2\\ -2 && 1\end{pmatrix},$ the reader can verify that $[T]_β = \frac 15\begin{pmatrix}-3 && 4\\ 4 && 3\end{pmatrix}.$ Since $β$ is the standard ordered basis, it follows that $T$ is left-multiplication by $[T]_β.$ Thus for any $(a, b)$ in $\Bbb R^2,$ we have

$T\begin{pmatrix} a\\ b\end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{5} \begin{pmatrix}-3 & 4\\ 4 & 3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{5} \begin{pmatrix}-3a + 4b \\ 4a + 3b\end{pmatrix}.$

---

There was a line written as:

> Since $T$ is linear, it is completely determined by its values on a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$.

However, it seems they are assuming $T$ to be linear and does the whole thing under this assumption but nowhere did they prove that indeed this transformation is linear. I think to prove $T$ is linear we need an explicit formula for $T$ which seems to be derived in here by assuming $T$ to be linear. This seems weird. Am I missing something?

Comment: What is the definition of a linear map, and does the reflection $T$ meet it?

Comment: You can prove that a reflection satisfies $T(av+bw)=aT(v)+bT(w)$ etc. without having an explicit formula for $T$ in coordinates, but only using your geometric knowledge of what a reflection is. The author assumes here we know that.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Oh, I see. Unfirtunately, I have no clue how to show it without having an explicit formula. It would be helpful if you consider letting me know about the geometric insights you're talking about.

Comment: @MarkBennet A mapping $T:V\to W$ where $V,W$ are vector spaces is a linear transformation iff $T(ax+b)=aT(x)+T(b)$ for all $a,b\in V$ and scalars $c$.

Comment: What definition of reflection would you want this proof to be based on?

Comment: @Al.G. Unfortunately, I don't understand what you're talking about. When I first studied reflections, only the idea of the thing got imprinted on my mind. It was, basically considering the object in space as a mirror and the given point getting reflected to it, thereby forming an image in the mirror which is the point "after reflection". This is all that I know.

Comment: Aha, but that is just a *physical* picture. You cannot *prove* whether it's linear or not, because linearity is a property only of functions defined on vector spaces. You first have to define a reflection in terms of this vector space, i.e. you have to define a map $R: V\to V$ that you call "reflection", and only then you can talk about if it's linear or not. You have to reformulate your physical picture into a mathematical one before *proving* things.

Comment: @Al.G. Then I would be really glad if you consider suggesting me a real definition.

Comment: (+1) I think this is a legitimate concern, because for example people (instructors, textbook authors) often will insist on using mathematical induction to prove something like $L(x_1 + x_2)=L(x_1)+L(x_2)$ implies $L$ distributes over any finite sum (see the discussion [here](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/27174/745)), which to me seems far more intuitively evident (examine the situation for a sum of $3$ things by writing $x_1 + x_2 + x_3$ as $(x_1 + x_2) + x_3$ and similarly for a sum of $4$ things) **(continued)**

Comment: than the fact that reflection is linear, since any kind of simple intuitively based conceptual understanding of reflections would be dependent on an a "picture-based" external real world visualization context, and not on a mathematical definition/representation of reflection in an ${\mathbb R}^2$ math-based context. I'm assuming the author hasn't previously done the latter for reflections. Even if so, I think some kind of proof like @Al.G. has done should be given, or at least an acknowledgment that such a proof is technically needed but avoided for some reason (that the author should state).

Answer (score 0):

You first have to *define* what a reflection means as a function on vector spaces, and only then prove that it's a linear transformation.

In $\mathbb R^2$, a line through 0, $ax+by=0$, is uniquely determined by its unit normal vector $u=(a,b)$. The line is then the set $\{x:x\cdot u=0\}$.

Now let's define what reflection means around this line for an arbitrary vector $v$. First, draw a picture:
[image]

How does the reflection of $v$ around $u$ - let's denote it by $R_u(v)$ - relate to the original vector $v$? Their difference, $R_u(v)-v$ should be (obviously from the picture) twice the projection of $v$ onto $u$, in the opposite direction.

The projection of $v$ on $u$ has length $(v\cdot u)$ because we chose $u$ to be a unit vector, hence the difference $R_u(v)-v$ must be (again, twice that, but in the direction opposite to $u$) $$R_u(v)-v=-2(v\cdot u)u.$$ Convince yourself that this also works if $u$ and $v$ lie in different half-planes with respect to the line we're reflecting about.

Therefore, we can define reflection in 2d around a line with unit normal $u$ as $$R_u(v)=v-2(v\cdot u)u.$$ Being a sum of two linear in $v$ functions ($v$ and $-2(v\cdot u)u$), it is also linear. You can also directly check the linearity property on this definition if you want :)